# How to assign column order level value programmatically in asp.net dynamic data

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4

I have stored order values in database.
Now I want to order table columns using their order values stored in database.
How to assign order level value programmatically in asp.net dynamic data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use expression trees in with Linq. See following link for the example.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/235860/Expression-Tree-Basics